# Python subprocess permission

Tags: python, unix, permissions, subprocess

When a command is executed via `subprocess.run`, what permissions is the command executed with? Is it the permissions of the enclosing python file? Is it user permissions?

For example, if a python file were run with sudo:

```
sudo python3 file.py
```

and file.py contained the line

```
subprocess.run([ 'chmod',  '+x',  'file.sh' ])
```

Would `chmod` be run with super user permissions?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115276/if-i-sudo-execute-a-bash-script-file-will-all-commands-inside-the-bash-script-b

Comment: ...that command wouldn't actually run at all. It would need to be `subprocess.run(['chmod', '+x', 'file.sh'])`, unless `shell=True` is passed (which it shouldn't be).

Comment: what about _not_ calling an external command and doing: `os.chmod(path, 0o755)`

Comment: Updated the command to be valid. There isn't a reason to run this; just wanted to give an example of a command requiring elevated privileges. The real example is very long :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively, it should, because, through `sudo`, you are giving the script itself superuser permissions - this means that the commands it runs would be effectively performed by the superuser.

However, to verify, let's do a little experiment.

`test.py`

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run('whoami')
```

(Now, on the terminal)

```
$ sudo python test.py
root
$
```

So, `chmod` will run with superuser permissions, yes.